# install SSL certificate on mirrored copy of VMWare instance?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Can a CSR generated on a VMWare instance be used to create a SSL certificate, and, installed on a "copied" version of this VMWare instance on a different server?

I would figure that they are basically a mirrored copy of one another, that this could be done.

Maybe for security reasons, the certificate won't install on the copied version because the CSR could be slightly different, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CSR is a certificate request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request). It's basically a text file with Base-64 encoded values. The process for its creation doesn't matter to the Certificate Authority. The origin/machine of the CSR doesn't matter. The values within the request matter (to you) -- DNS name, location, organization, etc.

Your Certificate Authority will respond to your request with a certificate. That certificate can be used on any machine. Once the certificate is received, you don't need the CSR anymore. The important part is where you install that certificate, and how it's configured along with your web server. Matching DNS host names being the most important.

Comment: So as long as the information you manually provide (DNS, location, org) is the same, then it should work?  Awesome, thanks!

Comment: That's right -- all that really matters is the common name (DNS host name). Certificates are portable between machines.